# Cannot define setOnRefreshListener for SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to assign a behavior different than the standard one when my swipelayout is refreshed:

This is my code:

```
 binding.refreshed = binding.refreshOtrosRequestList

        binding.refreshOtrosRequestList!!.setOnRefreshListener(SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
            [Change behavior]
                       })
```

These are the elements I'm using defined in the corresponding XML file:

```
<data>
    <variable name="refreshed" type="androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout"/>
</data>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refreshOtrosRequestList"
        app:onRefreshListener="@{() -> model.onRefresh(refreshed)}"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

But the defined setOnRefreshListener never fires:

What am I doing wrong?
PD: this is request, also in data in XML file:

```
  <data>
        <variable name="model" type="es.nscontrol.controlpresencial.viewmodels.NonWorkingDateViewModel"/>
        <variable name="refreshed" type="androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout"/>
    </data>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is "model"?

```
model.onRefresh(refreshed)
```

Is it somewhere defined?
Additionally, it looks strange when you use databiding to store view from this layout in a variable.

Edit:

I hope you also binded this "model" to the actual variable as you did with

```
binding.refreshed = binding.refreshOtrosRequestList
```

And invoke this after you binded these variables:

```
binding.executePendingBindings()
```

Comment: It is, check my edit, I also find it strange, but it's the way I found things done in the project and I don't think it's good to change it, just in case.

Comment: I edited my answer. 
I want to say that you should never send any view to viewmodel.
It is major mistake when you are using MVVM pattern.

Comment: Thanks, more and less it works, though there's an strange side effect, now the indicator of that the swipelayout is refreshing never ends, and a new refresh cannot be done, any idea on that?

Comment: You need to add app:refreshing="@{isRefreshing}" in XML to the SwipeRefreshLayout